# Enumerated Search Running Slow -- Obj C

Tags: objective-c, performance, cocoa, enumeration

I'm trying to create a search function that searches a mounted disk and all of its subfolders. The disk that I'm using to test doesn't have very many subdirectories (3-4 max?) and current search process takes roughly five or so seconds to complete. It isn't the end of the world, but I would like it to run a bit smoother.

Here is the code that I'm currently using:

```
NSMutableArray *testFiles = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

NSFileManager *localFileManager=[[NSFileManager alloc] init];
NSDirectoryEnumerator *dirEnum =
[localFileManager enumeratorAtPath:@"/volumes/"];


NSString *filename = (NSString *)dirEnum;
while ((filename = [dirEnum nextObject])) {
    if ([filename rangeOfString:@"stringName" options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch].length != 0) {
        [testFiles addObject:[@"/Volumes/" stringByAppendingPathComponent:filename]];
        NSLog(@"%@",testFiles);
    }
}
```

}

Any help is very much appreciated.

Comment: Something is very, very wrong there. enumeratorAtPath only enumerates items in _one_ directory. So this enumerator will only give you the names of all your mounted drives. I'd do an NSLog for each file to see what's going on.

Comment: @gnasher729, Whenever I run the code, it will effectively search all volumes and return values that match the string that I'm searching for no matter how many directories it has. Here is a sample output from the testFiles array code above save items marked with <> to preserve privacy...

`2014-05-02 16:09:23.853 <programName>[934:403] (
    "/Volumes/<CD>/<String>",
    "/Volumes/<ThumbDrive>/Directory One/Directory Two/<String> FILE.txt"`
)

Comment: I tried this again, with rather bizarre result. "/Volumes/" gives two results, .DS_Store and "Macintosh HD". "/Volumes/Macintosh HD" gives over a million files, using a Fusion drive.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the following in NSFileManager:

mountedVolumeURLsIncludingResourceValuesForKeys:options:

This gets a list of all volumes, so you can pick which ones you want. There are options to ignore hidden volumes (for example hidden Time Machine volumes).

enumeratorAtURL:includingPropertiesForKeys:options:errorHandler:

A different enumerator. Has options to allow skipping hidden files, and importantly to skip descendents of packages. For example, all the files inside an app package won't be enumerated.

In NSDirectoryEnumerator, check if you can call skipDescendants for some directories that you don't care about.

Or do it totally different and use Spotlight.